# Need globally installed dependencies in package.json on npm init

Tags: node.js, npm, dependency-management

I have globally installed packages like **bower**, **jshint**, etc. On running `npm init`, it does not include dependencies. Is there a way where dependencies would be pre-included in package.json using globally installed packages on running `npm init`.

Comment: `npm init` does exactly what it says; initializes a new project. Global dependencies are *not* automagically considered dependencies of your new project; that would defeat the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

No. If your project needs explicit dependencies, they must be added to `package.json` manually or with `npm install --save`

Answer (score 0):

npm init will creats a new package.json file based on your configuration that you specify. However you can use globally installed packages without specify them in package.json. But if you want to migrate your code from one system to another, then you have to manually specify all globally installed packages with name & version in package.json and after that you can use npm install for that.

Answer (score 0):

Global dependencies are not supposed to be your new project's dependencies. Global dependencies are supposed to be command line tools such as pm2, forever, mocha, Istanbul etc. Package.json and global dependencies serve totally different purpose.
If you still find the need of doing so please explain exact package you need both at global and project.

Comment: So, is there a way I can include globally installed packages in my package.json **automatically** on `npm init`.

Comment: Short answer: No.